# Is there a good approach at automatically incrementing maven versions

Tags: git, maven, continuous-integration

I've been going at this for a while, and here's the current scenario:

- I have a development branch where after every push, I want to publish my current maven library as a SNAPSHOT. I currently do this by using exec-plugin and echo to retrieve my maven version (e.g.: -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}' org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec))
- I then use the update-versions command to inject the "-SNAPSHOT" to it and publish (I don't publish it back to the branch, since I don't really want to keep the "-SNAPSHOT").

For release, I suppose I could do something similar where I retrieve the version, then figure out a way to increment it -> publish back to the currently active branch -> and then finally do a deploy. Right now, I went with a slightly easier although error-prone approach: I attempt to fetch the current version set in the artifactory we use and, if it exists, I fail the pipeline with a message stating that the version already exists. It's not great right now, because I'm actually inverting an error condition here, so if maven fails for any other reason, it actually assumes the version doesn't exist and keeps on going to the next steps. Ugh.

Now, the main points I was looking for here are really around the best method of handling maven projects and versioning. Ideally my goals are:

- be able to publish something as a SNAPSHOT properly (maybe without having to resort to maven-exec)?
- be able to update my version incrementally, so users don't have to constantly have to update their version? This process of course would have to ensure I don't push something to master that may have the wrong version (which would then fail at deploying). Edit: To rephrase, the intention here isn't just incrementing the version 'to the next one', but instead to the 'next available one', ensuring I don't try and merge a version that has been published before.

I do have one restriction: the tooling we use does not allow for us to have merge hooks (Azure DevOps with Azure Git). This means we are limited to pipelines on pulls (and PRs), and after a PR is merged.

I'm happy to take any other approach here realistically, I feel like I'm going out of my way to make something that should have a clear path by now, so I'm hoping for someone with some guidance here.

Answer (score 6):

A supplemental for @davidxxx answer.
The usage of build-helper maven plugin can improve that:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
    -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion}.0.0 \
    versions:commit
```

or like this:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
   - DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0 \
   versions:commit
```

without any sed etc. more details:

- https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html

Comment: I didn't know that parse-version goal. That is excellent. I will try that the next times :)

Comment: Ah, this helps me tremendously. This may indeed help me achieve what we intended, much appreciated.

Comment: I had a look at this, but doesn't help my case, since it doesn't actually look for the latest deployed version. Upon re-reading my question, this wasn't really clear, I'll update with this information. I'm thinking maybe the update-versions can be used to do this or at the very least retrieve the latest published release version.

Comment: Do you create tags in your version control? If so you could assume that the latest version from your version control is the same as the latest deployed if not. You have to find another way.

Answer (score 4):

> then use the update-versions command to inject the "-SNAPSHOT" to it
> and publish (I don't publish it back to the branch, since I don't
> really want to keep the "-SNAPSHOT".

Not a judgement but using a no snapshot version in the pom for both snapshot and release is error prone. Snapshot means "in dev, beware". Release means "quite stable, go".
In cases of doubt or to rollaback to a specific version, devs have to be sure of what a commit refers to. Here it is blurry.

> Ideally my goals> are:
>
> be able to publish something as a SNAPSHOT properly (maybe without
> having to resort to maven-exec)?

Two ways :

- keep your artifact version as `-SNAPSHOT` in your pom.xml and update it by stripping the
  `-SNAPSHOT` and tag/deploy it when you want consider it as a release.
- keep your artifact version as no `-SNAPSHOT` (while I don't advise) and use the
  [maven-ci friendly feature/plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) to set the version dynamically.

Your pom properties could look like a version defined as :

```
 <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>

 <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
    <changelist></changelist>
    <sha1/>
 </properties>
```

And you should also declare the  `flatten-maven-plugin` to keep the pom.xml consumable by other projects (which is the case for libraries).

At last you could execute the deploy goal to push your snapshot in your remote maven repository:

```
mvn -Dchangelist=-SNAPSHOT clean deploy
```

> be able to update my version incrementally, so users don't have to
> constantly have to update their version? This process of course would
> have to ensure I don't push something to master that may have the
> wrong version (which would then fail at deploying).

You could rely on maven plugins and scripting to achieve that.
For example to increment automatically the second digit of a version that doesn't have snapshot as prefix like in your case, on a linux system you can do :

```
// get the current pom version and store it into a variable
version=$(mvn -q -U -Dexpression=project.version -DforceStdout maven-help-plugin:evaluate)
// increment the second digit of the version and overwrite the variable
version=$(echo ${version} |  awk -F'.' '{print $1"."$2+1"."$3}' |  sed s/[.]$//)
// update the pom with the new version
mvn -U versions:set -DnewVersion=${version}
```

It works both for versions with 3 digits but also 2 digits thanks to the sed.

Comment: This is a really great comment, but most cannot be directly applied to my project. I haven't marked as solved and - while I do agree mostly with the SNAPSHOT comments AND I realise I did not give the full context - the versioning is something that is, for the most part, invisible to the developers, and not really reused somewhere else - maven is completely hidden from them in this scenario.

Comment: Update to comment above: my main question was auto-updating versions. It's a fair point on the snapshot, so there's room for improvement, I'll have to think about it based on your comments. This is not - unfortunately - a maven project per-se, since many of this logic is hidden away from the business users. It's just managed by maven underneath :)

Answer (score 0):

We built a tool (note: I'm working on it) to keep track of different versions, schemas and increments per branch.

You can define your schemas and your pins per branch. Also, you're not bound by SemVer, could use CalVer as well.

I.e., for SemVer you could set your project version to **semver**, while set branch pin for dev branch to **Major.Minor.Patch-SNAPSHOT**. Then it would increment your master branch with plain semver and dev branch will have *-SNAPSHOT* suffix.

There is either open source version here https://github.com/relizaio/versioning or SaaS version at https://relizahub.com (which has a lot of extra functionality). SaaS version is the one that would keep track of previous versions and allow you to do clean per-branch split via API.

Here is my write-up on details for all the above: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/

*Note:* This still needs a command in the end to inject version into your pom, for which the following may be used via [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html) (on top of suggestions from other answers):

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="$versionFromReliza"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit
```